# Which homology groups of a closed orientable 6-manifold can be isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}^3$?

Tags: algebraic-topology, manifolds, homology-cohomology

> List all $i$ for which there is a closed orientable $6$-manifold $M$ with $H_i(M) =\mathbb{Z}\oplus\mathbb{Z}\oplus\mathbb{Z}$.

I am working on an old exam problem and this one stumped me. Progress so far: 
I can take $Y=\mathbb{T}^3 \times \mathbb{S}^3$ and get the desired group for $i =1,5,2,4$ I think. But this construction I believe gives $H_3(Y)=\mathbb{Z}^2$. What to do in this case?

Comment: Try using products of smaller manifolds. And of course, assuming connectivity, you're limited in terms of the dimension

Comment: I see, thank you! So from this I can take Y=T^3 X S^3 and get the desired group for i =1,5,2,4 I think. But this construction I believe gives H_3(Y)=Z^2. Can you help me with this case? I think I would need three two-manifolds ,M_1,M_2,M_3 with H_1(M) right?

Comment: New users often make a mistake by trying to pack the entire problem into the title and then (as here) use the body of the Question to provide editorial context.  Please make the body of the Question as self-contained as practical, and use the title creatively to attract attention by highlighting what *kind* of problem you need help with.

Comment: For $i = 3$ you're constrained by Poincare duality.

Comment: Thank you Qiaochu Yuan, I may be a little dense. But Poincare duality gives us that H^3(M)=H_3(M) for a 6-manifold right? I don't see how that gives me a constraint.

Comment: For I=3, you would get odd Euler characteristic, so the product of smaller manifolds approach can't work.

Comment: Of course! Thank you Steve D and Qiaochu Yuan I understand now :)

Comment: @chachoman: Poincare duality gives you more than this. Think about the cup product on $H^3$.

Comment: Do you want $\otimes$?

Comment: Do you mean $\mathbb{Z}^3 = \mathbb{Z} \oplus \mathbb{Z} \oplus \mathbb{Z}$, or do you mean $\mathbb{Z}^{\otimes 3} = \mathbb{Z} \otimes \mathbb{Z} \otimes \mathbb{Z} \cong \mathbb{Z}$? You've written two different things...

Comment: @Najib Idrissi I mean direct sum not tensor :)

Comment: @NajibIdrissi Luckily, the answer is the same for both!

Answer (score 3):

First of all, $Y = T^3\times S^3$ is indeed a closed orientable six-dimensional manifold with $H_i(Y; \mathbb{Z}) \cong \mathbb{Z}^3$ for $i = 1, 2, 4, 5$. Furthermore, $H_0(Y; \mathbb{Z}) \cong \mathbb{Z}$, $H_3(Y; \mathbb{Z}) \cong \mathbb{Z}^2 $, and $H_6(Y; \mathbb{Z}) \cong \mathbb{Z}$.

It is also possible to find a closed orientable six-dimensional manifold $M$ with $H_i(M; \mathbb{Z}) \cong \mathbb{Z}^3$ for $i = 0, 6$. For example, $M = S^6\sqcup S^6\sqcup S^6$. However, if we also require $M$ to be connected, no such example exists.

So the only question which remains is whether there exists a closed orientable six-dimensional manifold $M$ with $H_3(M; \mathbb{Z}) \cong \mathbb{Z}^3$. Suppose $M$ is such a manifold and fix an orientation. By Poincaré duality, $H^3(M; \mathbb{Z}) \cong H_3(M; \mathbb{Z})$ and cup product defines a non-degenerate bilinear form

\begin{align*}
H^3(M; \mathbb{Z})\times H^3(M; \mathbb{Z}) &\to \mathbb{Z}\\
(\alpha, \beta) &\mapsto \langle \alpha\cup\beta, [M]\rangle
\end{align*}

where $[M] \in H_6(M; \mathbb{Z})$ is the fundamental class of $M$ and the angled brackets on the right denote the pairing between cohomology and homology - note, in general the cup product is non-degenerate on $H^3(M; \mathbb{Z})_{\text{free}}$, but for our given $M$, $H^3(M; \mathbb{Z})$ has no torsion. Note that

$$\alpha\cup\beta = (-1)^{3\times 3}\beta\cup\alpha = -\beta\cup\alpha,$$

so the above form is skew-symmetric.

Choose a basis for $H^3(M; \mathbb{Z})$. The corresponding matrix representation of the form is a $3\times 3$ integer matrix $A$. As the form is non-degenerate, $A$ is non-singular (i.e. $\det A \neq 0$), and as the form is skew-symmetric, $A$ is skew-symmetric (i.e. $A^T = -A$). Note that

$$\det A = \det A^T = \det (-A) = (-1)^3\det A = -\det A,$$

but this is impossible as $\det A \neq 0$. Therefore, no such $A$, and hence $M$, can exist.

---

More generally, the proof above can be modified to give the following result:

> Let $M$ be a closed orientable manifold of dimension $4n + 2$. Then the rank of $H^{2n+1}(M; \mathbb{Z})$ is even, i.e. $b_{2n+1}(M)$ is even.

Together with Poincaré duality, this gives rise to the following corollary:

> Let $M$ be a closed orientable manifold of dimension $4n + 2$. Then $\chi(M)$ is even.

In contrast, for any integer $k$, there exists a closed orientable manifold $M$ of dimension $4n$ with $\chi(M) = k$. In particular, such manifolds can have odd Euler characteristic, e.g. $M = \mathbb{CP}^{2n}$ which has Euler characteristic $\chi(\mathbb{CP}^{2n}) = 2n + 1$.